# How do I set an arg of a generic type using React's useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm building a form component that takes a callback that accepts an arg of a generic type, but I'm running into some difficulty when I try to update the arg in the form:

Here's how I'm calling the form component:

```
// FormPage.tsx

type MyConfirmationOptions = {
  isFoo?: boolean;
};

<MyForm<MyConfirmationOptions>
  onConfirm={({ isFoo }) => {
    api.postData(isFoo)
  }}
/>
```

And here's the form where I'm running into issues:

```
// MyForm.tsx

interface MyFormProps<T> {
  onConfirm: (confirmationOptions: T) => void;
}

export function MyForm<T>(
  props: PropsWithChildren<MyFormProps<T>>,
){
  const [confirmationOptions, setConfirmationOptions] = useState<T>({} as T);

  const onSubmit = (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    onConfirm(confirmationOptions);
  };

  return (
    ...
    <Checkbox
      ...
      onChange={async () => {
        setConfirmationOptions(confirmationOptions => {
          ...confirmationOptions,
          isFoo: !confirmationOptions.isFoo
        })
      }}
      checked={confirmationOptions.isFoo}
    />
  )  
}
```

The first error I get is in the `onChange` when I try to spread `confirmationOptions`: *Type 'T' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator*

The second error is in the `checked` prop: *Property 'isFoo' does not exist on type 'T'*

Lastly, I'm not enjoying casting my initial `useState` value to `T`.

I did check my tsconfig, and I have the following:

```
"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
```

Answer (score 1):

> The first error I get is in the onChange when I try to spread confirmationOptions: Type 'T' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator

If `T` is *too* generic, you cannot assume it is spreadable.

> The second error is in the checked prop: Property 'isFoo' does not exist on type 'T'

If `T` is *too* generic, you cannot assume it may have a `isFoo` property.

If you need to refer to the `isFoo` property inside your form, you have to narrow the condition like:

```
type HasFoo = {
  isFoo?: boolean;
}

type MyConfirmationOptions = { other stuff... } & HasFoo;

interface MyFormProps<T> {
  onConfirm: (confirmationOptions: T) => void;
}

function MyForm<T extends HasFoo>({ onConfirm }: PropsWithChildren<MyFormProps<T>>){
  const [confirmationOptions, setConfirmationOptions] = useState<T>({ isFoo: false } as T);

  const onSubmit = (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    onConfirm(confirmationOptions);
  };

  return (
    <div
      onChange={async () => {
        setConfirmationOptions(
           confirmationOptions => ({
             ...confirmationOptions,
             isFoo: !confirmationOptions.isFoo
           })
        )
      }}
    />
  )  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I type narrow as you suggest, I get the following error in my `onChange`:
`Argument of type '(confirmationOptions: T) => T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.` and 
 `'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '(confirmationOptions: T) => T'`